# How to disable multiple workspaces on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: workspaces, 22.04

I would like to have only 1 workspace on ubuntu. How to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be done within the "Multitasking" settings. Here's how to configure it:

1. Open the "Settings" application:
   [image: Settings]
2. Select "Multitasking" from the left menu:
   [image: Settings - Multitasking]
3. Scroll down a bit to "Workspaces", select "Fixed number of workspaces", then set the number to any that you would like.

Comment: This works to only have one workspace but still have to click to get started. How do I get Ubuntu to start right to desktop.

Comment: dconf key is `/org/gnome/mutter/dynamic-workspaces`

Comment: Those using Ubuntu 20.04 and have Gnome Tweaks - go to `Tweaks` -> `Workspaces` -> Choose `Static Workspaces` -> Set the `Number of Workspaces` to 1