# What is the key for workspace count in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gsettings

I want to automate the workspace count mentioned in [How to disable multiple workspaces on Ubuntu 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407649/how-to-disable-multiple-workspaces-on-ubuntu-22-04)

I would prefer to use `gsettings` but I can't find the key.

What is the key there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct command is this one:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces 1
```

Taken from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1792995/110454)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use something like:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.dynamic-workspaces 1
```

You can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> auto completion to discover many of the settings

Comment: Thank you @matigo, but I can't find `dynamic-workspaces` using `gsettings get` and tabs.